# Overloading when inheriting from two differently-templated copies of the same class

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, virtual

I'm writing an input-handling system for a game that I'd like to make extensible to arbitrary event types. I'd like to design an interface-like specification that allows me to enforce that certain objects are expected to handle certain events; for instance via something like `class Player : public EventHandler<KeyboardEvent>`. My proposed design for such a thing is as follows.

```
template <class T>
class EventHandler {
public:
    void handleEvent(T event) { doHandleEvent(event); };
private:
    virtual void doHandleEvent(T event) {};
};

class InputHandler : public EventHandler<Action>, public EventHandler<CursorEvent> {};
```

However, at the point where I call `InputHandler::handle()`, the above produces the following errors. It appears that `handleEvent()` for both templated versions of `EventHandler` is treated as the same function. I was under the impression that since the two versions of `handleEvent` have different argument types, the result should be as if `InputHandler` had one overloaded function with the two possible argument types.

Why doesn't C++ allow this, and what are some better alternatives to what I'm trying to do? I suspect the above may not be good practice.

```
/Users/smichaels/Projects/danmaku/src/SDL/Input.cpp:35:34: error: member 'handleEvent' found in multiple base classes
      of different types
                if (act) handler.handleEvent(act.get());
                                 ^
/Users/smichaels/Projects/danmaku/src/SDL/../Input/InputHandler.hpp:15:14: note: member found by ambiguous name lookup
        void handleEvent(T event) { doHandleEvent(event); };
             ^
/Users/smichaels/Projects/danmaku/src/SDL/../Input/InputHandler.hpp:15:14: note: member found by ambiguous name lookup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class InputHandler :
  public EventHandler<Action>,
  public EventHandler<CursorEvent>
{
public:
  using EventHandler<Action>::handleEvent;
  using EventHandler<CursorEvent>::handleEvent;
};
```

in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can instead write:

```
template<class...Bases>
struct ManyHandler:Bases...{
  using Bases::handleEvent...;
};
template<class...Events>
using EventsHandler=ManyHandler< EvendHandler<Events>...>;
```

then

```
class InputHandler : public EventsHandler<Actions, CursorEvent >{};
```

and if you also have

```
class OutputHandler : public EventsHandler< Messages, Sounds >{};
```

we can write

```
class IoHandler : public ManyHandler< InputHandler, OutputHandler > {};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is just what I was looking for!